How to pass endUserMetadata to a tool in GCP conversational agent?
I have created an agent in GCP Conversational Agents. There is one playbook and a tool (Open API). To interact with the chatbot, I have enabled the Conversational Messenger integration.
I want to send some context information regarding the user to my tool as one of its inputs. The setContext function seems useful.
This is how I am setting the context
const dfMessenger = document.querySelector('df-messenger');
const metadata = {
  "userId": "dhfsliouhfsliufsdhguijksdfh",
};
dfMessenger.setContext(metadata);

However, I am not clear on how to pass the userId as a parameter to my tool.
